# Generating a ssh Host config file out of a Supperputty XML file

Tags: shell-script, ssh, awk, xml, ssh-config

I am building a script that generates an ssh config file out of a Supperputty XML Session config file. I don't know which tool could handle it better. I try to achieve it with awk, but I don't receive the expected results since the fields are never the same.

inputfile:

```
<SessionData SessionId="DMZ contoso.prod.net" SessionName="amq01.contoso.prod.net" ImageKey="computer" Host="amq01.contoso.prod.net" Port="22" Proto="SSH" PuttySession="[webserver]-[EL]# PROD | xx" Username="user" ExtraArgs="" SPSLFileName="" />
<SessionData SessionId="Build und Deploy/[Websphere]-[IR]# Deploy" SessionName="[Websphere]-[Internal]# Deploy" ImageKey="computer" Host="deploy.contoso.prod.net" Port="22" Proto="SSH" PuttySession="[Websphere]-[internal]# Deploy" Username="usa" ExtraArgs="" SPSLFileName="" />
<SessionData SessionId="ImportedFromPuTTY/[DP]-[DMZ]# PROD | 01" SessionName="[DP]-[DMZ]# PROD | 01" Host="192.168.1.91" Port="2354" Proto="SSH" PuttySession="[DP]-[DMZ]# PROD | 01" Username="schnipi" SPSLFileName="" />
```

expected Output:

```
#short info
Host Hostfromfile
  HostName amq01.contoso.prod.net
  User user
  Port 22
```

I already tried it some ways but only the third one somehow works, because SessionId always stays at the same position:

```
        awk 'if ( $2 ~ /SessionId="/,/\/"/ ) {print "#Test "$2}
        awk -F '="' '{print($2 == /SessionId/) "#Test " $2 ""}' session >> Test.conf
        awk -F '="' '{print "#Description: " $2 "\n" }' session >> Test.conf
        awk -F '="' '/SessionId=/ {for (a=1;a<=NF;++a) if ($a~/SessionId=/) print "# " $a "\n"} ' session >> config
```

I don't know how to only Output the match between the quotes without the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
IFS=$'\n'
for i in `cat file.xml`
do
        echo "$i" | awk -F '"' '{print "#Discription: " $2 "\nHost internal\n  HostName " $8"\n  User " $16 "\n  Port "$10 }'
done
```

output which i got as:

```
#Discription: DMZ contoso.prod.net
Host internal
  HostName amq01.contoso.prod.net
  User user
  Port 22
#Discription: Build und Deploy/[Websphere]-[IR]# Deploy
Host internal
  HostName deploy.contoso.prod.net
  User web
  Port 22
```

Comment: nice try and a good solution. Unfortunately my XML has 200Hosts and some have been imported from putty, what causes the result to shift the $fields. Example: `Hostname: 22   User:    Port SSH`
Like I said, The fields are not always the same. Thats why I try to catch where the Patterns like `/patternA=/,/"/ /PatternB=/,/"/` I added an example Putty import